# Corollary from the counterexample to a version of the Riesz lemma with $r=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Riesz's lemma states that given a Banach space $X$ and a closed subspace of it $M$ there exists $x\in X$ with $||x||_\infty =1$ and $d(x,M)\geq 1-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.
A counter example for the case $\epsilon=0$ is with $$X=\{f\in C[0,1];f(0)=0\}$$ $$M=\{g\in X;\int_0^1g=0\}$$ indeed one proves that for $f\in X$ with $||f||_\infty=1$ 
$$d(f,M)=|\int f|<1$$ 
and then $\forall g\in M$:
$$(1)\ \ |\int f|=|\int (f-g)|\leq \int|f-g|\leq\int||f-g||_\infty=||f-g||_\infty$$
I need to show that there exists $f\in X-M$ such that $\forall g\in M$
$$d(f,M)<||f-g||_\infty$$
My argument is that the final inequality in $(1)$ is actually a strong inequality from continuity of $f,g$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$. However, I feel that I am missing something and will be glad for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since both $f$ and $g$ are continuous and vanish at $0$, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ with $|f(x) - g(x)| \le \frac12 \, \|f-g\|_\infty$. Hence,
$$\int |f-g| \, \mathrm dx = \int_0^\varepsilon |f-g| \, \mathrm dx + \int_\varepsilon^1 |f-g| \, \mathrm{d} x \le \Big(\frac\varepsilon2 + (1-\varepsilon)\Big) \, \|f-g\|_\infty < \|f-g\|_\infty.$$

Comment: So i am not missing anything. That's good news