# Distance From Functions Set Is Not Attained

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I have to find a funtion $f\in C[0,1]$ which implies that $f(0)=0, ||f||_{\infty}=1$ and $\forall g\in C[0,1]$ s.t $\int_{0}^{1}g(t)dt=0=g(0)$, $||f-g||_{\infty}\geq1$.i.e $d(f,M)$ is not attaind when $M=\{g\in C[0,1]|g(0)=\int_{0}^{1}g(t)dt=0\}$.

I think somehow "have the sense" of how this function should look like: it should wobble a lot between $-1$ and $1$ s.t it will be 'far enough' from zero all the time, but I have no idea how to construct it.

Comment: Why do you think that such a function should exist? I would imagine it actually doesn't exist.

Comment: This question almost looks like a duplicate to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304923/corollary-from-the-counterexample-to-a-version-of-the-riesz-lemma-with-r-1/2305249#2305249

Comment: cool, thanks :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If $\|f\| = 1$ and $\|f-g\| \ge 1$ then you must have $f(x) =\alpha$ ae. for some $|\alpha| = 1$.